# How can I find out the currency sub-unit (aka minor unit) symbol in Java?

Tags: java, currency

Currency.getSymbol will give me the major symbol (e.g. "$" for USD) but I'd like to get the minor unit (e.g. "p" for GBP or the cents symbol for USD), without writing my own look up table.

Is there a standard, i.e. built in way to do this?

Comment: +1 I suspect not. BTW, Not all currencies have a minor symbol. There are three cent characters ¢, ￠ and ₡

Comment: +1 You can use [List of countries, territories and currencies](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-5000500.htm) to implement the lookup map.

Comment: Personally I'd look at [the ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/) or [Joda-Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/) for this kind of data, but both seem to lack this specific piece of information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would like to suggest for this situation to use custom `custom currency format`. Use `DecimalFormat` or  `NumberFormat` of `java.text.*` package.
There are a lot of example for that.

Example

```
public class CurrencyFormatExample {
    public void currencyFormat(Locale currentLocale) {
        Double currency = new Double(9843.21);
        NumberFormat currencyFormatter;
        String currencyOut;
        currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);
        currencyOut = currencyFormatter.format(currency);
        System.out.println(currencyOut + " " + currentLocale.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Locale[] locales = new Locale[]{new Locale("fr", "FR"),
            new Locale("de", "DE"), new Locale("ca", "CA"),
            new Locale("rs", "RS"),new Locale("en", "IN")
        };
        CurrencyFormatExample[] formate = new CurrencyFormatExample[locales.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < locales.length; i++) {
            formate[i].currencyFormat(locales[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Out put:

```
9Â 843,21 â?¬ fr_FR

9.843,21 â?¬ de_DE

CAD 9.843,21 ca_CA

RSD 9,843.21 rs_RS

Rs.9,843.21 en_IN
```

Reference [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/i18n/currency-format.shtml):

**Update for minor currency**

```
  Locale locale = Locale.UK;
  Currency curr = Currency.getInstance(locale);

  // get and print the symbol of the currency
  String symbol = curr.getSymbol(locale);
  System.out.println("Symbol is = " + symbol);
```

Output :

```
Symbol is = £
```

Comment: How does this answer the submitter's question?  As far as I can see, this code outputs the major currency symbol for each locale, not the minor currency.

Comment: Sorry, but I think the submitter is asking for a symbol or code for the sub-unit (such as '¢' for USD or 'p' for GBP).  See answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023754/do-minor-currency-units-have-a-iso-standard for details.  According to that answer, there is no international standard for these.